# Segmentation fault on write in shared memory

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, shared-memory

I made a project in Netbeans and it works there fine. But when I'm trying to compile using makefile I receive Segmentation fault. Why cannot I access to shared memory? Should I use char*?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static std::string *shmem;  //shared memory

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    //open file and copy content
    std::ifstream ifs("example.txt");
    std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                     (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    size_t size = content.size();

    //create shared memory page and copy content
    shmem = static_cast<std::string*>(mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
                MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
    *shmem = content;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Makefile

```
CC      = g++
CFLAGS  = -c -Wall -std=c++11 -pthread
LDFLAGS = -pthread
SOURCES = main.cpp
OBJECTS =$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=MapReduce

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not cast the return type of mmap to a std::string. std::string is a c++ non-POD type. You would need to call the constructor of std::string which would then likely perform dynamic allocation (however, it could use small string optimization). This would lead to the string not actually living in shared memory except for perhaps it's size field depending on how it is implemented.

If you want to store a string buffer in shared memory you should just use a char*, or look at libraries like [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/interprocess.html). The library is cross platform and will make putting all kinds of types in shared memory much simpler, of course at the cost of pulling in Boost.

Answer (score 1):

First rule of such problems: Always check system calls return value.
Second rule of such problems: Run in a debugger, and learn to use postmortem analysis.

In your particular case, the mmap failed, but you failed to check its return code, which means you tried to dereference the pointer `-1`.

I'm not sure precisely why the mmap failed, but when I actually create `example.txt`, it stops failing on my machine. It would seem to me that you also failed to check for return code from the code preparing the buffer for mapping.

Lastly, std::string does not work the way you think it works. Allocating memory to it using mmap would simply not do the right thing. std::string allocates its own memory, and if you want it to reside on an explicitly mmaped space, you need to look up giving it a custom allocator.

**Edited to add**

If you insist on allocating your `std::string` in the mmap (as opposed to the data the string is supposed to contain), then the size you send to the mmap should `sizeof(std::string)`, and not `string.length`. This would still not be semantically correct, as you would invoke the `std::string.operator=` without first constructing the object. A working program would, therefor, be:

```
std::string *func(const std::string &str)
{    
    //create shared memory page and copy content
    void *memory = mmap(NULL, sizeof(std::string), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    if( memory==MAP_FAILED ) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    std::string *allocated_string = new(memory) std::string();
    *allocated_string = str;

    return allocated_string;
}
```

This correctly places an initialized `std::string` into the mmaped memory. It uses placement new in order to initialize it (you will need to include `<new>`). Again, this is, likely, not what you want, as the `std::string` will reside in your mmaped memory, but that actual string will, likely, not.

Answer (score 0):

Use placement new to construct std::string at shmem location

```
new (shmem) std::string(content)
```

But this will likely still not work for interprocess communication just because of

- std::string layout may be different due to compiler options (or kind of compilet)
- std::string internal fields refer to other memory, local to your process as grepsedawk already pointed